# Netlogo BehaviorSpace - exporting histogram at specific tick

Tags: netlogo, behaviorspace

Wondering if anyone knows how to export the data from a histogram plot at a specific tick e.g. tick 40?

Previously I have successfully exported histogram data at the end of each run by typing the following in the 'Final commands' box within BehaviorSpace:
`export-plot "Bus times" (word "/mnt/HA/groups/WalkingDistTests/bus_"random-float 1.0".csv")`
but I can't figure out where I would type a similar command for a mid-simulation export e.g., `if ticks = 40` .

I'd like to do this in BehaviorSpace, if possible, to make it easier to modify the directory path for where I want to file saved.

Any ideas would be super appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Certainly, you can just put that statement in the GO procedure, probably at the end and before the `tick` statement:

```
if ticks = 40 [export-plot ... ]
```

Also:  your life will be easier if you include the BehaviorSpace run number in the export file name, instead of a random number. Replace `"random-float 1.0"` with `behaviorspace-run-number`. Then you will know which run produced which file.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Steve. This was going to be my back up but I was hoping to avoid nesting commands in the code itself because it will make it more cumbersome when I need to modify the directory path for where I want the output saved. I figured it would be easier to do all in the BehaviorSpace window if possible but I guess its not that simple.
And, I will definitely make that change now and use `behaviorspace-run-number`